# Dialog box filter for edit text minimum charatures

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have set up a dialog box with one edit text box. I used a set filter for max number of charactures allowed but I dont see an a filter for minimum. I added code to add "x" to entered text if the user enters less than 8 chars. Code compiles but crashes. 
and throws Error is "string longer than 9". and gives (16 as piece.length()). could use some help solving

```
      public void onClick(View item) {

  final EditText input = new EditText(this);

  switch (item.getId()) {
  case R.id.textView1:
  strEditText = Title1.getText().toString(); // OK

  input.setText(strEditText);
  input.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8) }); // Set max # of charactures for Input


        for (int i = 0; i < strEditText.length(); i++) {                            //
            String piece = strEditText;                                             //

            String toBeAdded = "";                                                  //
            if (piece.length() < 8) {
                int length = piece.length();
                toBeAdded = piece;
                while (length < 8) {
                    toBeAdded = toBeAdded + "X";
                    length++;
                }
            } else if (piece.length() > 8) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error, string longer than 9");
            } else {
                toBeAdded = piece;
            }
            strEditText = strEditText + toBeAdded;

        }// return to for-loop                                                      //

        new AlertDialog.Builder(ElsEditTitles.this)

        .setTitle("Ttile").setView(input).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                strReturn = input.getText().toString();
                Title1.setText(strReturn);

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        }).show();

        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Cant Understand Why You Put This For : for (int i = 0; i < strEditText.length(); i++)

For Example if EditText is 'abc' strEditText is 'abc' and that for repeats 3 Time.
in First Time toBeAdded = 'abcXXXXX' and when code "strEditText = strEditText + toBeAdded;" run strEditText = 'abcabcXXXXX' and when That for goes into 2nd loop its Already more than 8 character and throws your Error.

Sorry For My Bad English..

Comment: That was creating the error. Thank you I will post the changes I made for reference.